# Error with negative bins while melting dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe 'd' like this:

```
   breaks counts.x counts.y
1     -20        1        1
2     -15        0        1
3     -10        0        5
4      -5        4       18
5       0       13       27
6       5       18       25
7      10        9       12
8      15        2        1
9      20        1        7
10     25       NA        0
11     30       NA        1
```

When I try to melt using 'breaks'  as id variable it is giving me the following error:

```
 d=melt(d,id=breaks)
Error in varnames[id.vars] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

How can I resolve this?
I have to draw a ggplot using breaks on x axis and counts on y axis.

Comment: If you are getting an error running this code, it could be a package conflict. Try restarting R.

Comment: I think you have a typo. Either use `melt(d, id = "breaks")` (quote `breaks`) or `melt(d, id = 1)`.

Comment: We need a [Minimum Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Please dump the output of `dput(your_data_frame)`

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, is this the kind of ggplot you want to obtain ?

[image]

If yes this is the code behind it:

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(breaks = c(-20, -15, -10, -5,  0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30),
                counts.x  = c(1, 0, 0 ,4 , 13, 18, 9, 2, 1, NA, NA),
                counts.y = c(1, 1, 5, 18, 27, 25, 12, 1, 7 , 0, 1))

d <- melt(d, id = "breaks")

ggplot(d, aes(x = breaks, y = value)) + geom_point(aes(colour = variable)) +
       labs(title = "Bins vs. Counts", x = "Bins", y = "Counts") +
       theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

Comment: YEs.. I have to make ggplot same as yours but I was getting an error while melting.

Comment: Because @pinky you had `d <- melt(d, id = breaks)` which can fail in two ways - first you must have an object called `breaks` lying around otherwise R will give `object 'breaks' not found` and secondly because you passed the *value* of breaks (ie a vector of numeric values) rather than the name of the id column as a scalar character value as the answerer here has done correctly with `melt(d, id = "breaks")` - the quote marks are **vital**.

Answer (score 1):

Not a fix to your exact problem, but an alternative solution would be to try `library(tidyr)`:

```
library(tidyr)
d <- gather(d,"variable","value",2:3)
```

And it will give you columns 2:3 as rows.